# Ember.js RestAdapter configure to use asp.net ashx handler for all (GET,POST,DELETE,PUT)

Tags: asp.net, ember.js, ashx

I am trying to find out how it would be possible to configure `RestAdapter` of the ember.js framework in order all of its find, create, update, delete functions that match to `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` or `DELETE` hit a SampleHanlder.ashx file that I have created in my ASP.NET web application.

The configuration described in the guides makes the url to hit likewise:

```
<domain>/SampleHandler.ashx/people/1
```

But the `/people/1` path after the SampleHandler.ashx I don't know how it can be used in a handler. If a handler can use this path how is that done?

Is there a way to configure `RestAdapter` or Ember.js in general to use for the rest functions of my store an ashx handler?

Answer (score 0):

Ember expects that each model (or model collection) has a unique endpoint within your API.  You'd probably want to look at extending the `RESTAdapter` to create a new adapter that does what you need.